# playframework scala returning post request

Tags: scala, playframework

in my scala playframework application I want to return the via Post submitted and then with slick stored object back to frontend as json

I tried this:

```
  def createClient = Action.async { implicit request =>
    request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ClientModel] match {
      case JsSuccess(client) =>

        clientDTO.createClient(client).map { clients =>
          Ok(Json.toJson(clients))
        }

    })
  }
```

but I get this error:

[image]

[image]

what could be my problem?

**NEW ERROR**
[image]

Comment: Try and add a `match` for `JsError` as well

Comment: I hade one before. does not return any helpful stuff ... doesnt compile at the moment

Comment: what version of play are you using?

Comment: I'm using playframework 2.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [playframwork controller return ID of created object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421389/playframwork-controller-return-id-of-created-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with something along these lines:

```
  def createClient = Action.async { implicit request =>
    request.body.asJson match {
      case None => // do something that returns a Future[Result] ~ such as NotFound or
      case Some(js) =>
        js.validate[ClientModel] match {
          case client: JsSuccess[ClientModel] =>
            clientDTO.createClient(client).map { clients =>
              Ok(Json.toJson(clients))
            }
          case e: JsError => // do something that returns a Future[Result] ~ such as InternalServerError
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You do realize my suggestion is not complete and it has commented parts, right?

Answer (score -1):

the .async, as the name suggests require a Future type.
You have 2 options:

- Remove the .async, this will make your def synchronous (deprecated)
- Leave the .async but return a Future result

  ```
  def createClient = Action.async { implicit request =>
      request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ClientModel] match {
          case JsSuccess(client) =>

              clientDTO.createClient(client).map { clients =>
                  Future(Ok(Json.toJson(clients)))
              }

      })
  }
  ```

But you still need to add the case of validation error:

```
case JsSuccess(client) =>
{
    clientDTO.createClient(client).map 
    {
        clients => Future(Ok(Json.toJson(clients)))
    }
}
case _ => Future(BadRequest(""))
```

This should work and, in all the cases apart JsSuccess, the function will return a future BadRequest response.
A better solution is to change the _ with JsError:

```
case e: JsError => 
{
   Println(e)
   Future(BadRequest(.....))
}
```

This will also print the error.

You can read more here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson
(Using validation chapter)

More about future in scala: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html